# RegEx in BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I need to split the following field:  `LP1234354_CD12346`

and get the 2 separate columns with the following values:`1234354` and `12346`. 
I tried regex and right/left but not successful. Thank you in advance!
Dummy data:

```
SELECT 'LP1234354_CD12346' AS word UNION ALL
  SELECT 'LP1234456_CD12345'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'LP1234354_CD12346' AS word UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'LP1234456_CD12345' 
)
SELECT id, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(word, r'(\d+)')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS val1, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(word, r'(\d+)')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS val2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved.